# angular4.x, parameter of ngOnChanges method

Tags: angular, typescript

Here is a official demo code snippet:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: {[propKey: string]: SimpleChange}) {}
```

My question is the parameter of `ngOnChanges`.

`changes` is the parameter, after the symbol `:`, is the type annotation.

I am confused about the `{[propKey: string]: SimpleChange}`.

It's seems not like a destructuring and not like `opt: {key: string}`.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types

Comment: @MurhafSousli The question is I am confused about the `[propKey: string]`

Comment: That is not a question, if you want an answer, you need to ask a clear question! btw to remove your confusion you can use `changes: SimpleChanges` instead

Comment: @yurzui Thanks! This is the anwser my looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It suggests that if your property(key) is of type **string** then it will return an object of type **SimpleChanges**. This is something related to typescript, not with angular.

Let's dig into some more detail:-

Let's say **changes** object has something like this `{name: SimpleChange, age: SimpleChange}`. Then this type validation means if you passed key in string,
 say `"minor"` then it will return an object of **SimpleChange**.

```
let updatedNameChanges  = changes["name"]; 
// name is in string, so updatedNameChanges will be a SimpleChange object.
```

Furthermore, if you wanted to skip this, you can. The only difference will be of type casting and validation.

You can also use this as ref:

```
 ngOnChanges(changes: {[propKey: string]: SimpleChange}) {
   let log:string[] = [];
   for (let propName in changes) {
     let changedProp = changes[propName];
     let to = JSON.stringify(changedProp.currentValue);
     if (changedProp.isFirstChange()) {
       log.push(`Initial value of ${propName} set to ${to}`);
     } else {
       let from = JSON.stringify(changedProp.previousValue);
       log.push(`${propName} changed from ${from} to ${to}`);
     }
}
```

For further details, [try this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types)

Answer (score 0):

`{[propKey: string]: SimpleChange}` is the interface that describe an array of `SimpleChange`objects and `propKey` as string index (a dictionary).

So changes: `{[propKey: string]: SimpleChange}` is an array of `SimpleChange` object and `propKey` string indexes